# T-SQL XPath query to join an Attribute from an ancestor to a child element

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have the following XML document fragments:

```
<document id="856" version="004010" direction="outbound">
  <xpaths>
    <xpath id="deliverAddressCode">//ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId="N1"]/N1[N101="ST"][N103="ZZ"]/N104/text()</xpath>
  </xpaths>
  <schema>
    <BSN BSN01="00" BSN02="{xpath::concat(substring(asn[1]/asnH[1]/senderId[1],1,5),asn[1]/asnH[1]/dino[1])}" BSN03="{xpath::.//asnH/date/text()}" BSN04="{xpath::.//asnH/time/text()}" />
    <DTM DTM01="011" DTM02="{xpath::.//asnH/shipDate/text()}" />
    <HL HL01="1" HL02="" HL03="S">
      <TD1 TD101="PLT" TD102="{xpath::.//asnH/loadingQty/text()}" TD103="" TD104="" TD105="" TD106="N" TD107="{xpath::.//asnH/zWeight/text()}" TD108="KG" />
      <TD5 TD501="" TD502="" TD503="" TD504="M" TD505="{sql::select [dbo].[fsLocalToRemoteMapping]('{xpath::.//asnH/baanId/text()}','{xpath::.//asnH/ISAusageIndicator}','forwardingAgents','{xpath::.//asnH/cfrw/text()}')}" />
      <TD3 TD301="TL" TD302="" TD303="{xpath::.//asnH/trackingNo/text()}" />
      <PER PER01="IC" PER02="?" PER03="EM" PER04="?@?.com" />
      <N1 N101="SF" N102="{xpath:://sf/nama/text()}" N103="ZZ" N104="{xpath:://sf/cuno/text()}">
        <N3_SF N301="{xpath:://sf/namc/text()}" />
        <N4_SF N401="{xpath:://sf/cityName/text()}" N402="{xpath:://sf/prov/text()}" N403="{xpath:://sf/pstc/text()}" N404="{xpath:://sf/country/text()}" />
      </N1>
      <N1 N101="ST" N102="{xpath:://ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId='N1']/N1[N101='ST'][N103='ZZ']/N102/text()}" N103="ZZ" N104="{xpath:://ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId='N1']/N1[N101='ST'][N103='ZZ']/N104/text()}" />
    </HL>
  </schema>
  <scripts>
    <function id="fCDEC">   function fCDEC(x) { if(x  &gt;= 3500.00) return "002" ; else return "002"; }</function>
  </scripts>
</document>
```

and this (fragment of above):

```
<schema>
  <BSN BSN01="00" BSN02="{xpath::concat(substring(asn[1]/asnH[1]/senderId[1],1,5),asn[1]/asnH[1]/dino[1])}" BSN03="{xpath::.//asnH/date/text()}" BSN04="{xpath::.//asnH/time/text()}" />
  <DTM DTM01="011" DTM02="{xpath::.//asnH/shipDate/text()}" />
  <HL HL01="1" HL02="" HL03="S">
    <TD1 TD101="PLT" TD102="{xpath::.//asnH/loadingQty/text()}" TD103="" TD104="" TD105="" TD106="N" TD107="{xpath::.//asnH/zWeight/text()}" TD108="KG" />
    <TD5 TD501="" TD502="" TD503="" TD504="M" TD505="{sql::select [dbo].[fsLocalToRemoteMapping]('{xpath::.//asnH/baanId/text()}','{xpath::.//asnH/ISAusageIndicator}','forwardingAgents','{xpath::.//asnH/cfrw/text()}')}" />
    <TD3 TD301="TL" TD302="" TD303="{xpath::.//asnH/trackingNo/text()}" />
    <PER PER01="IC" PER02="? EDI Services" PER03="EM" PER04="?@?.com" />
    <N1 N101="SF" N102="{xpath:://sf/nama/text()}" N103="ZZ" N104="{xpath:://sf/cuno/text()}">
      <N3_SF N301="{xpath:://sf/namc/text()}" />
      <N4_SF N401="{xpath:://sf/cityName/text()}" N402="{xpath:://sf/prov/text()}" N403="{xpath:://sf/pstc/text()}" N404="{xpath:://sf/country/text()}" />
    </N1>
    <N1 N101="ST" N102="{xpath:://ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId='N1']/N1[N101='ST'][N103='ZZ']/N102/text()}" N103="ZZ" N104="{xpath:://ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId='N1']/N1[N101='ST'][N103='ZZ']/N104/text()}" />
  </HL>
</schema>
```

How do I retrieve the document id from the first fragment to the second one so the query result is:

```
<schema id="856">
  <BSN BSN01="00" BSN02="{xpath::concat(substring(asn[1]/asnH[1]/senderId[1],1,5),asn[1]/asnH[1]/dino[1])}" BSN03="{xpath::.//asnH/date/text()}" BSN04="{xpath::.//asnH/time/text()}" />
  <DTM DTM01="011" DTM02="{xpath::.//asnH/shipDate/text()}" />
  <HL HL01="1" HL02="" HL03="S">
    <TD1 TD101="PLT" TD102="{xpath::.//asnH/loadingQty/text()}" TD103="" TD104="" TD105="" TD106="N" TD107="{xpath::.//asnH/zWeight/text()}" TD108="KG" />
    <TD5 TD501="" TD502="" TD503="" TD504="M" TD505="{sql::select [dbo].[fsLocalToRemoteMapping]('{xpath::.//asnH/baanId/text()}','{xpath::.//asnH/ISAusageIndicator}','forwardingAgents','{xpath::.//asnH/cfrw/text()}')}" />
    <TD3 TD301="TL" TD302="" TD303="{xpath::.//asnH/trackingNo/text()}" />
    <PER PER01="IC" PER02="? EDI Services" PER03="EM" PER04="?@?.com" />
    <N1 N101="SF" N102="{xpath:://sf/nama/text()}" N103="ZZ" N104="{xpath:://sf/cuno/text()}">
      <N3_SF N301="{xpath:://sf/namc/text()}" />
      <N4_SF N401="{xpath:://sf/cityName/text()}" N402="{xpath:://sf/prov/text()}" N403="{xpath:://sf/pstc/text()}" N404="{xpath:://sf/country/text()}" />
    </N1>
    <N1 N101="ST" N102="{xpath:://ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId='N1']/N1[N101='ST'][N103='ZZ']/N102/text()}" N103="ZZ" N104="{xpath:://ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId='N1']/N1[N101='ST'][N103='ZZ']/N104/text()}" />
  </HL>
</schema>
```

The query used

```
    --ALTER function [dbo].[fxDocSchema](@env varchar(10),@baanId varchar(10),@docId varchar(10)) returns xml as
    begin
        declare @baanId varchar(10)='010-000164',@env varchar(10)='test',@docId varchar(10)='856'
    --return(

    select t.c.query('.')
                 ,t.c.query('schema')
    from (select meta from EdiMeta where baanId=@baanId and env=Case Lower(@env)                                                                                                                                                 when 't' then 'test'
                                                                                                                                                 when 'p' then 'production'
                                                                                                                                                 else @env
                                                                                                                                     end) f(x)
    cross applyx.nodes('meta/partners/partner/documents/document[@id=sql:variable("@docId")]') t(c) 
    --)

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @XML XML = N'<document id="856" version="004010" direction="outbound">
  <xpaths>
    <xpath id="deliverAddressCode">//ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId="N1"]/N1[N101="ST"][N103="ZZ"]/N104/text()</xpath>
  </xpaths>
  <schema>
    <BSN BSN01="00" BSN02="{xpath::concat(substring(asn[1]/asnH[1]/senderId[1],1,5),asn[1]/asnH[1]/dino[1])}" BSN03="{xpath::.//asnH/date/text()}" BSN04="{xpath::.//asnH/time/text()}" />
    <DTM DTM01="011" DTM02="{xpath::.//asnH/shipDate/text()}" />
    <HL HL01="1" HL02="" HL03="S">
      <TD1 TD101="PLT" TD102="{xpath::.//asnH/loadingQty/text()}" TD103="" TD104="" TD105="" TD106="N" TD107="{xpath::.//asnH/zWeight/text()}" TD108="KG" />
      <TD5 TD501="" TD502="" TD503="" TD504="M" TD505="{sql::select [dbo].[fsLocalToRemoteMapping](''{xpath::.//asnH/baanId/text()}'',''{xpath::.//asnH/ISAusageIndicator}'',''forwardingAgents'',''{xpath::.//asnH/cfrw/text()}'')}" />
      <TD3 TD301="TL" TD302="" TD303="{xpath::.//asnH/trackingNo/text()}" />
      <PER PER01="IC" PER02="?" PER03="EM" PER04="?@?.com" />
      <N1 N101="SF" N102="{xpath:://sf/nama/text()}" N103="ZZ" N104="{xpath:://sf/cuno/text()}">
        <N3_SF N301="{xpath:://sf/namc/text()}" />
        <N4_SF N401="{xpath:://sf/cityName/text()}" N402="{xpath:://sf/prov/text()}" N403="{xpath:://sf/pstc/text()}" N404="{xpath:://sf/country/text()}" />
      </N1>
      <N1 N101="ST" N102="{xpath:://ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId=''N1'']/N1[N101=''ST''][N103=''ZZ'']/N102/text()}" N103="ZZ" N104="{xpath:://ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId=''N1'']/N1[N101=''ST''][N103=''ZZ'']/N104/text()}" />
    </HL>
  </schema>
  <scripts>
    <function id="fCDEC">   function fCDEC(x) { if(x  &gt;= 3500.00) return "002" ; else return "002"; }</function>
  </scripts>
</document>'

SELECT 
    x.value('@id', 'int') AS "@Id"
,   (
    Select 
        y.query('.') AS "*"
    FROM @XMl.nodes('document/schema/*') AS a(y)
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    )
FROM @Xml.nodes('document') AS a(x)
FOR XML PATH('schema')
```

Five principles:

1. I isolate the main level of what I want at the root to the main query(the outer a(x) which is the root of 'document')
2. I isolate the children(a(y)) and do a query on all the children of document/schema/*.  So if you ran the inner by itself you would see all the children nodes on three rows.
3. I don't care about them so I just use the query to get all of their parts and label them as text "*".
4. I specify this is a type of XML in the nested select but don't want to give it another level on it, just keep itself. (For XML Path(''), TYPE)
5. I then set the attribute for the main Id again and then do another FOR XML expression to just get the path but ignore the root setting (For XML Path('schema'))

Answer (score 0):

Using the [insert XML DML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/insert-xml-dml).

```sql
DECLARE @tt TABLE(x XML);
INSERT INTO @tt(x)VALUES(N'<document id="856" version="004010" direction="outbound">
  <xpaths>
    <xpath id="deliverAddressCode">//ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId="N1"]/N1[N101="ST"][N103="ZZ"]/N104/text()</xpath>
  </xpaths>
  <schema>
    <BSN BSN01="00" BSN02="{xpath::concat(substring(asn[1]/asnH[1]/senderId[1],1,5),asn[1]/asnH[1]/dino[1])}" BSN03="{xpath::.//asnH/date/text()}" BSN04="{xpath::.//asnH/time/text()}" />
    <DTM DTM01="011" DTM02="{xpath::.//asnH/shipDate/text()}" />
    <HL HL01="1" HL02="" HL03="S">
      <TD1 TD101="PLT" TD102="{xpath::.//asnH/loadingQty/text()}" TD103="" TD104="" TD105="" TD106="N" TD107="{xpath::.//asnH/zWeight/text()}" TD108="KG" />
      <TD5 TD501="" TD502="" TD503="" TD504="M" TD505="{sql::select [dbo].[fsLocalToRemoteMapping](''{xpath::.//asnH/baanId/text()}'',''{xpath::.//asnH/ISAusageIndicator}'',''forwardingAgents'',''{xpath::.//asnH/cfrw/text()}'')}" />
      <TD3 TD301="TL" TD302="" TD303="{xpath::.//asnH/trackingNo/text()}" />
      <PER PER01="IC" PER02="?" PER03="EM" PER04="?@?.com" />
      <N1 N101="SF" N102="{xpath:://sf/nama/text()}" N103="ZZ" N104="{xpath:://sf/cuno/text()}">
        <N3_SF N301="{xpath:://sf/namc/text()}" />
        <N4_SF N401="{xpath:://sf/cityName/text()}" N402="{xpath:://sf/prov/text()}" N403="{xpath:://sf/pstc/text()}" N404="{xpath:://sf/country/text()}" />
      </N1>
      <N1 N101="ST" N102="{xpath:://ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId=''N1'']/N1[N101=''ST''][N103=''ZZ'']/N102/text()}" N103="ZZ" N104="{xpath:://ib//Transaction[1]/Loop[@LoopId=''N1'']/N1[N101=''ST''][N103=''ZZ'']/N104/text()}" />
    </HL>
  </schema>
  <scripts>
    <function id="fCDEC">   function fCDEC(x) { if(x  &gt;= 3500.00) return "002" ; else return "002"; }</function>
  </scripts>
</document>');

DECLARE @doc_id INT=856;

SELECT
    s=x.n.query('.')
INTO
    #x
FROM
    @tt AS tt
    CROSS APPLY tt.x.nodes('/document[@id=sql:variable("@doc_id")]/schema') AS x(n);

UPDATE
    #x
SET
    s.modify('insert attribute id {sql:variable("@doc_id")} into (/schema[1])')

SELECT * FROM #x;

DROP TABLE #x;
```

Comment: Isn't there a more elegant way.. this seems an overkill

Comment: @TonyP Elegant is a subjective qualification, so I can't answer that. In any case, if you want to change the schema element using XML `insert`, you first need to select it to a temporary table (or table variable). That is because the modify function does not allow changing XML in ad-hoc SQL queries (IOW on the fly). That is why the schema nodes are selected into a temporary table first, the XML is then changed in the temporary table and finally the result is selected from the temporary table.